# How to create a query not attached to a model

Tags: strapi

Strapi uses bookshelf (or Mongoose) to manage the model of the entities it manages. This is fairly convenient, and is useful when querying the data in these models.

My problem comes when I'm trying to do a query that is an aggregation. Imagine, if you had a `Todo` model with two fields: `name` and `done`, you could easily get the list of `Todo`s by doing (in the `services/Todo.js`):

`Todo.query().fetchAll()`

But what is what I want is a count of how many todos are done and not done. Essentially, I want to execute:
`SELECT done, count(*) as howMany FROM todo GROUP BY done`

I can create the query, and it executes it... but it fails, because it tries to use the results of the query to hydrate a Todo object and it complains that there's no `name`.

So, this is the question: Does strapi provide a "general purpose" query capability that I can use to run model-detached queries?

I'd like to be able to use the same DB connections that strapi is using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not intuitive and the documentation is not clear about that.
But you can access to mongoose and knex instance in `strapi.connections.default`.

Hope it help.

---

An example of the use would be:

```
const knexQueryBuilder = strapi.connections.default('mytable');
knexQueryBuilder.where('myfield','=','myvalue');
const resp = await knexQueryBuilder.then();
console.log('Results: ', resp);
```